# Laravel 4 - Scope to only show rows where another DB has no relational items

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I have a cars table, and a car_image table.

I want to get all the cars that have NO images in the car_image.

In my car model I am making a scope:

```
public function scopeNoImages($query)
{
    return $query-> ??
}
```

How can I create a scope that will show only results from the cars table that have no related rows in the pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the car_image consists of the images of the cars:

In your `Car` model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('CarImage');
}
```

In your `CarImage` model:

```
public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Car');
}
```

Now you can load the cars without images like so:

```
return Car::doesntHave('images')->get();
```

Using: [doesntHave](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_doesntHave).

Comment: Perfect, I do have an images hasMany relationship already so thats a nice function! Thanks.